# Java Hashmap: get all keys greater than X value

Tags: java, java-8, hashmap, java-stream

```
 import java.util.*;
 import static java.lang.String.format;

 public class Dumpground {

     private static final String[] fruits = new String[]{"apples", "bananas", "grapes", "oranges", "watermelons", "kiwis"};
     static Map<String, Long> expirationMap;

     public static void main(String[] args) {
         long expiration = 1L;
         expirationMap = new HashMap<>();
         for (String fruit : values()){
             expirationMap.put(fruit, expiration);
             expiration++;
         }
         for (Map.Entry<String, Long> item : expirationMap.entrySet()) {
               String key = item.getKey();
               Long value = item.getValue();
               System.out.println(format("key: %s, value: %s", key, value));
           }


     }

     public static String[] values() {return fruits;}
 }
```

OUTPUT

```
key: oranges, value: 4
key: watermelons, value: 5
key: kiwis, value: 6
key: bananas, value: 2
key: apples, value: 1
key: grapes, value: 3
```

I am trying to find a clever ways to grep all keys where its values are greater than X

for example, if X == 3, it should return oranges, and watermelons and kiwis

the obvious way is just iterate through map and compare the value, but is there easy, concise way to do it?

Comment: *"is there easy, concise way to do it?"* Streams would seem to be what you're looking for.

Comment: It seems you need to do a filter on the map. See https://www.mkyong.com/java8/java-8-filter-a-map-examples/

Comment: If you want ordering you should be using a `TreeMap`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Streams, yes. Use

```java
expirationMap.entrySet().stream()
    .filter(entry -> entry.getValue() > 3L)
    .map(Entry::getKey)
    .toList();
```

to get a list of the keys.

We need to stream over the map entries rather than the values or keys only, because we need to compare the one (the value) and return the other (the key). Okay, one *need not*, as nullpointed out in the comments.

The `filter` method gets the value and compares it to 3, discarding elements not greater than 3; and then we map the entries to their values using the `map` method. Finally, we collect the result into a `List`.

Comment: *We need to stream over the map entries*... It's not a must though. Detailed in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54773064/1746118)

Comment: @nullpointer for most maps, e.g. `HashMap` and `TreeMap`, it’s rather inefficient to iterate only over the keys and perform a lookup for each of them, whereas `Map.Entry` provides access to the value for free.

Comment: @Holger *access to the value for free*.. that still means `O(1)`(same as a lookup) isn't it? In this context, would mapping the entry to key further wouldn't incur some cost again? I understand though that the difference should ideally be something to be least worried about, just wondering to clarify the concepts in detail.

Comment: @nullpointer `O(1)` doesn’t mean “for free”. It only denotes that the costs are independent to other variables, like the number of contained elements. There’s still a difference between `HashMap.Entry.getValue()`, which just reads a field, and `HashMap.get(…)`, which calculates a hash code, reads an array entry, invokes `equals` on the key, and perhaps has to handle collisions. And that’s for every key here. Not to speak of `TreeMap`, where lookup is `O(log n)`.

Answer (score 4):

See below for another readable approach.

```
expirationMap.forEach((key, value) -> {
     if (value > x) {
         System.out.println(format("key: %s, value: %s", key, value));
     }
});
```

The .forEach part will iterate over the map's entrySet() and extract each entry's key and value respectively onto (key, value).

Answer (score 3):

A slightly different variation using just set and key lookup:

```
Set<String> greppedKeys = expirationMap.keySet().stream() // keyset only
        .filter(key -> expirationMap.get(key) > 3L) // X here being 3L
        .collect(Collectors.toSet()); // all keys would be unique anyway
```

Answer (score 2):

This will do the trick using streams :

```
expirationMap.entrySet().stream().filter(e -> e.getValue() > 3)
             .forEach(e -> {
                 System.out.println("key " + e.getKey() + "value" + e.getValue());
              });
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach apart from what others have done can be to use [`Interface Predicate<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html) whose default method `test(T t)` can be used to evaluate values greater than 3.

```
  Predicate<Long> filterGreater3 = f-> f>3;
  expirationMap.entrySet()
               .stream()
               .filter(x->filterGreater3.test(x.getValue()))
               .forEach(System.out::println);
```